Using Python heapq.heapify(Array)
I want to use heapq.heapify(Arr) but everytime i want a slice of array to be used without creating new memory allocation for the new array. I want the rest of the array to be as is. example: heapq.heapify(arr[0:3]) and use rest of arr[3::] in some calculation and go on changing this slice width in a loop. Can I do it? I dont see arr being heapified in this case

Do you mean (numpy) array or (native) list?

"without creating new memory allocation for the new array" - Why?

Why do you wanna do this? For what application? Do you have any inputs and expected outputs?

Pretty sure you're going to have to write your own implementation that works like this instead of with a builtin list.

You can use a custom _heapify(), but depending on your implementation, it may require additional space, unless you implement the entire heap:
import heapq


def _heapify(arr, s, e):
    partition = arr[s:e]
    heapq.heapify(partition)
    arr[s:e] = partition


arr = [i - 1 for i in range(31, 10, -1)]

res = []
for i in range(1, len(arr) - 2):
    _heapify(arr, 0, i + 3)
    res += (arr[:i + 3], arr[i + 3:])

print(res)



Prints
[[27, 29, 28, 30], [26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10], [26, 27, 28, 30, 29], [25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20,

19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10], [25, 27, 26, 30, 29, 28], [24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10], [24, 27, 25, 30, 29, 28, 26], [23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10], [23, 24, 25, 27, 29, 28, 26, 30], [22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10], [22, 23, 25, 24, 29, 28, 26, 30, 27], [21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10], [21, 22, 25, 24, 23, 28, 26, 30, 27, 29], [20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10], [20, 21, 25, 24, 22, 28, 26, 30, 27, 29, 23], [19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10], [19, 21, 20, 24, 22, 25, 26, 30, 27, 29, 23, 28], [18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10], [18, 21, 19, 24, 22, 20, 26, 30, 27, 29, 23, 28, 25], [17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10], [17, 21, 18, 24, 22, 20, 19, 30, 27, 29, 23, 28, 25, 26], [16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10], [16, 21, 17, 24, 22, 20, 18, 30, 27, 29, 23, 28, 25, 26, 19], [15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10], [15, 16, 17, 21, 22, 20, 18, 24, 27, 29, 23, 28, 25, 26, 19, 30], [14, 13, 12, 11, 10], [14, 15, 17, 16, 22, 20, 18, 21, 27, 29, 23, 28, 25, 26, 19, 30, 24], [13, 12, 11, 10], [13, 14, 17, 15, 22, 20, 18, 21, 16, 29, 23, 28, 25, 26, 19, 30, 24, 27], [12, 11, 10], [12, 13, 17, 14, 22, 20, 18, 21, 15, 29, 23, 28, 25, 26, 19, 30, 24, 27, 16], [11, 10], [11, 12, 17, 14, 13, 20, 18, 21, 15, 22, 23, 28, 25, 26, 19, 30, 24, 27, 16, 29], [10], [10, 11, 17, 14, 12, 20, 18, 21, 15, 13, 23, 28, 25, 26, 19, 30, 24, 27, 16, 29, 22], []]


"it may require additional space": not "may", but sure does require additional space. The asker explicitly asked "without creating new memory allocation"...

@trincot What if they implement the heap from scratch? It seems to me that they need to use some sort of segment trees for whatever they wanna do. But the purpose is unclear in the question. You're right.

I think the purpose is quite clear. They want to heapify a section of the list inplace.
